# How to 'setState' only to the appBar icons instead of 'notifyListeners'

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I have an appBar with one icon, this icon has a number which have to be updated after I change somethings in the app. I was using notifyListeners(), but this command is cleaning a list I need so I have to update that number in appbar without notifyListeners().

I tried to call SetState but it doesn't worked.. is there a way to update only the app bar?

In provider which I include more items:

```dart
  void setBadge() {
    _number = number;
    notifyListeners(); // this line I dropped out
  }
```

App bar Icon widget:

```dart
class AppBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Cart>(
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined),
        onPressed: () async {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ROUTE_CART);
        },
      ),
      builder: (_, cart, child) {
        return BagBadge(
          child: child,
          value: cart.isEmpty ? '' : cart.number.toString(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

BagBadge:

```dart
class BagBadge extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final String value;

  BagBadge({
    @required this.child,
    @required this.value,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        child,
        if (value != '')
          Positioned(
            right: value.length < 4 ? 20 : 10,
            top: 30,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(value.length < 4 ? 2 : 3),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor
              ),
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: 16,
                minWidth: 16,
              ),
              child: Text(
                value,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code that is causing your problem.

Comment: See the Update .

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to update the value of BagBadge without `notifyListeners()`

Comment: Why is the setState() is not working for you? What it says?

Comment: It updates only the screen itself, not the appBar

Comment: The appBar is on the screen... What is the difference? What is the expected result and what is the actual result?

Comment: Current Result: Not updating the number stacked with the icon in AppBar. Expected Result: Update the number in AppBar

Comment: The AppBarWidget is a stateless widget for you. Modify it to be a stateful widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: this would work only if you use a stateful widget. With stateless widget the change won't be shown.

You can try something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppBarWidgetState createState() => _AppBarWidgetState();
}

class _AppBarWidgetState extends State<AppBarWidget> {
  int _appBarValue = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Cart>(
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined),
        onPressed: () async {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ROUTE_CART);
        },
      ),
      builder: (_, cart, child) {
        return BagBadge(
          child: child,
          value: _appBarValue == 0 ? '' : '$appBarValue',
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

  setAppBarValue(int value) {
     setState(() { _appBarValue = value; });
  }
}
```

Whenever you want to change the value, just call the `setAppBarValue()` function.

Comment: Please edit the question and show us how the code exactly looks like. How the appBar built, how do you try to change the value...

Comment: Maybe is there a way to use `notifyListeners()` but only for the icon consumer?